# How to get trailing slash back in an .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have tried almost all possible solutions for getting a trailing slash in my url but somehow it seems to conflict with the rest of my rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

### START WWW & HTTPS

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

### END WWW & HTTPS
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

#1)externally redirect "/file.php" to "/file"   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
#2)Internally map "/file" back to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

`Domainname.com/example` still does not automatically go to `domainname.com/example/`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is not about programming, better go to e.g. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Cross-site post on Webmasters: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118502/htaccess-please-help-getting-trailing-slash-back